# Python Flask Only Run Code Once

Tags: python, flask, global-variables

I am trying to set a global variable as in:

```
    # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,flash, url_for, session, request
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased, Query
from sqlalchemy import exc
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from .forms import *


import zlib
#from sqlalchemy.orm.query import limit, order_by
from dbmodel import *


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'
Bootstrap(app)

MAX_ITEMS=50
MAX_ZIPS=5
MAX_ORDERS=20


clientMaxSQL="SELECT * FROM CLIENT WHERE 1"

engine, dbsession = dbconnect() 

@app.route("/clientRegister",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def clientRegister():
        form = ClientQuery()

        global clientMaxSQL
        flash('maxSql at start %s ' %(clientMaxSQL))
        if form.reset.data == "True":
                flash('RESET TABLE FILTERS')
                clientMaxSQL="SELECT * FROM CLIENT WHERE 1"

        sql = clientMaxSQL
        if form.validate_on_submit():
                if len(form.compareVal.data.strip()) > 0 and ( any(c.isalpha() for c in form.compareVal.data) or any(c.isdigit() for c in form.compareVal.data)):
                        sql = sql + " AND " + form.columnSelection.data + form.comparisonSelection.data + "'" +form.compareVal.data+"'"

        start=int(request.args.get('start', '0'))
        prev=start-MAX_ITEMS
        nextStart = start + MAX_ITEMS
        tmpSQL = clientMaxSQL
        clientMaxSQL = sql
        sql = sql + " LIMIT " + str(start)+","+str(nextStart)
        try:
                clients = engine.execute(sql)
                maxStart=engine.execute(clientMaxSQL).rowcount
                flash('Attempting Query: %s' %(sql))
        except:
                flash('Invalid Comparison of %s' %(form.compareVal.data))
                sql = tmpSQL + " LIMIT " + str(start)+","+str(nextStart)
                clientMaxSQL=tmpSQL
                clients = engine.execute(sql)
                maxStart=engine.execute(clientMaxSQL)
        flash('maxSql at end %s ' %(clientMaxSQL))
        return render_template("clientRegister.html",form=form,maxStart=maxStart,clients=clients,start=start, prev=prev,nextStart=nextStart)
```

I am getting some strange results. It seems as if this statement (declared above all of my function definitions) is executing every once in a while on its own. Is this possible? It is imperative to my web app that this only runs once otherwise I will lose the current state of my query.

Added all the code in the program that ever changes the variable. It is resetting on its own though.

Comment: Doesn't this just set a string to a variable?

Comment: show your full code. this is only a string it can not execute on it's own.

Comment: "It is imperative to my web app that this only runs once otherwise I will lose the current state of my query." ...no idea what you're trying to achieve but this sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @salmanwahed I posted all the code.The idea is that I am trying to maintain state of the query until the user resets it

Comment: And what happens when you get more than one user on your site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Python and Apache mod\_wsgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541301/global-variables-in-python-and-apache-mod-wsgi)

Answer (score 2):

use the, `@app.before_first_request` decorator with the function to make it run only once

As in:

```
@app.before_first_request
def function_to_run_only_once():
     #your statement(s)
```

This should make sure that your said statements execute only once in the entire lifetime of your program